# Investor and share Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I'm trying to write a contract that :

1. Show current value
2. investor can buy share before sale start (contract is sealed when it starts), and each investor get his own equity
3. As the profit grows during sale, the dividend should based on unchangeable equity.(investor's equity * profit)
4. (*optional) During sale, if investor withdraw his equity, others get his equity equally

That's what I want to achieve in my contract, anyone here to give me some idea about this? like contract struct, variables you should use....anything could be helpful!

Appreciate and waiting

For your help. Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad and you ask about opinion-based advices. First thing I can suggest is try to write contract on your own. If you will have any errors try to find solution in the internet first. In case that doesn't help, come back to this site and be sure to use search before asking specific question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It's true that I need to write it on my own but I even don't know where to start. The task just say some investors are able to "buy share" and "withdraw share"....So the first thing I need to figure out is contract struct...or some ideas